# How can I authenticate kubectl to an AWS EKS cluster from a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, continuous-integration, amazon-eks

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab to deploy a full AWS EKS cluster using Terraform. I got that to work rather well, but now I want to be able to perform some tasks on the cluster from that pipeline. Specifically, I am following [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/840b3aceff471404e2deb1c813c1ac94508db6c1/doc/user/project/clusters/add_existing_cluster.md) guide from Gitlab on how to manually add one to Gitlab and am trying to put that in a script.

Now my issue is when I need to perform `kubectl` commands from within the pipeline, but I cannot figure out how to authenticate from there without actually creating a custom image containing the `aws-iam-authenticator` from AWS to authenticate. That honestly doesn't seem like the right way to do it, so I figure there has to be another way, a better way.

Maybe I am thinking totally wrong and I do not need to use `kubectl` and there is a totally different approach I can take. If that's true, please tell me so. If not, I'd love to know if there is a different way.

I have been researching the different ways of authenticating with a k8s cluster, but every single resource I have found that is tailored for EKS insists I need to use the `aws-iam-authenticator` program.

Comment: `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name>`. You will then be able to use `kubectl` without `aws-iam-authenticator`.

Comment: @jordanm When you do that, you get a kubeconfig that uses the aws command instead. I am looking for a way to authenticate without the use of any external commands.

Comment: You can create and use a static authorization token, but I would advise against that for security reasons.